# How to base64 encode a PDF file in Python

Tags: python, encoding, base64, xml-rpc

How should I base64 encode a PDF file for transport over XML-RPC in Python?

Comment: this is really a non-question, as xmlrpclib does this for you

Comment: Actually, that fact turned out to be the answer.  I just didn't know about it when I asked the question.

Answer (score 26):

If you don't want to use the xmlrpclib's Binary class, you can just use the .encode() method of strings:

```
a = open("pdf_reference.pdf", "rb").read().encode("base64")
```

Comment: Doesn't this read the entire file by calling `read()` before encoding it? Is that how it's supposed to work? I can't imagine encoding a multi-MB file or larger with this.

Comment: @Shurane it's a one-line example of using the encode method of strings.  Optimising performance will be application specific and is left as an exercise.

Comment: this no longer works in Python 3, try this: `base64.b64encode(open('path/to/your.pdf', 'rb').read())` credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43084065/5125264

Answer (score 5):

Actually, after some more digging, it looks like the `xmlrpclib` module may have the piece I need with it's `Binary` helper class:

```
binary_obj = xmlrpclib.Binary( open('foo.pdf').read() )
```

Here's an example from the [Trac XML-RPC documentation](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/XmlRpcPlugin)

```
import xmlrpclib 
server = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy("http://athomas:password@localhost:8080/trunk/login/xmlrpc") 
server.wiki.putAttachment('WikiStart/t.py', xmlrpclib.Binary(open('t.py').read()))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with the [base64 library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html), legacy interface.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might be able to use the [binascii](http://docs.python.org/library/binascii.html) module

> binascii.b2a_base64(data)
>
> Convert binary data to a line of ASCII characters in base64 coding. The return value is the converted line, including a newline char. The length of data should be at most 57 to adhere to the base64 standard.