# Convert pdf file to base64binary to use in a Biztalk XML input file

Tags: python, xml-serialization, base64, biztalk

I'm writing a Python program to build s an XML file that will be processed by Biztalk to import data into another system.

One of the fields allows me to include a file in a `base64binary` field.
I'm doing so using `base64.b64encode(data)`:

```
import base64
data = open('Test.pdf', 'rb').read()
print base64.b64encode(data)
```

However the expected data must begin with a `0x`.

Looking into a sample XML file I find that the example encoded data looks like hexadecimal (no symbols and no letters above `F`) so I also tried that with no luck:

```
import binascii
print '0x' + binascii.hexlify(data)
```

How can you use Python to properly encode a file to insert it into a `base64binary` XML field?

Comment: Judging from this http://www.schemacentral.com/sc/xsd/t-xsd_base64Binary.html standard base64 should be fine. Wonder why it's not in this particular case.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208894/how-to-base64-encode-a-pdf-file-in-python/208960#208960

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that `base64`, as outlined in my question's code, *is correct*. There was a misinterpretation of the error logs.

So if anyone reading this has a similar problem, let me assure you: `base64` is fine, the problem must be something else.

Comment: In my case, I was trying to encode PDF files to Base64 too. and it worked perfectly. You've saved me a alot of time!