# What is the best way to convert a pdf file into base64Binary?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pdf, ipython

Using python, I want to `convert a pdf file into base64Binary`

My logic(not python) is reading the contents of the file into a byte array and then use something like `Convert.ToBase64String() method` to get the `Base64 string`:

```
byte[] pdfBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(pdfPath);
string pdfBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(pdfBytes);
```

Please let me know what is the right approach to `convert a pdf file into base64Binary` in python

Comment: THIS IS NOT PYTHON

Comment: I have edited my post. let me know if something is still unclear

Answer (score 50, accepted):

its easy as this

```
import base64

with open("book.pdf", "rb") as pdf_file:
    encoded_string = base64.b64encode(pdf_file.read())
```

source: [Encoding an image file with base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715493/encoding-an-image-file-with-base64)

Comment: It says: "a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'". :/

Comment: Ok, solved, this was for the tests I miss to "fake pdf".encode()

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
import base64
from base64 import b64decode, b64encode

def pdf_to_base64(file):
    file_bytes = base64.b64encode(file.read())
    base_64 = file_bytes.decode("ascii")
    return base_64
```