# Saving a PDF file to SQL Server 2019

Tags: python, sql-server, project

I need to save a PDF for every specific person in my Python code.

How do I save that file to a SQL Server table?

I have looked online but all I understood was you need to convert it to bytes or something. Not something we learned in school :)

Comment: you literally said it yourself. https://stackoverflow.com/a/43084065/14385360 and https://base64.guru/developers/python/examples/decode-pdf

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best way to convert a pdf file into base64Binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43083955/what-is-the-best-way-to-convert-a-pdf-file-into-base64binary)

Comment: @marc_s 2019 whoops

Answer (score 0):

Save and Read PDF File Using SQL Server and C#
[1]: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/013102/save-and-read-pdf-file-using-sql-server-and-C-Sharp/